# a webApp using UiApp and SpreadSheetApp in a Library

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a library containing a webApp (using UiApp with doGet) intended to work with a specific spreadsheet from each user of that library.

How a user of that library could pass the Id of his own spreadsheet to the library?

Thanks

Notes about the current code, on the library (myLib)

```
var mainDoc = SpreadsheetApp.openById("abc123"); // should be user's spreadsheet Id 
function mainUiApp() {   
  // something here using handler1 below 
  return app; 
}
function handler1() {
  // using mainDoc spreadsheet 
}
```

Notes about the current code, on the user of myLib

```
var mainDocClient = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xyz789");
function doGet() {
  return myLib.mainUiApp();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a spreadsheet ID as a parameter of the `mainUiApp` function. Here is an example

The `myLib` code is

```
var mainDoc = null;

function mainUiApp(ssID) {   
  mainDoc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID);
  // ...
  return app; 
}
```

User code is

```
function doGet() {
  return myLib.mainUiApp("xyz789");
}
```

Comment: that's a great idea, however there is a problem: when using mainDoc within handler1 function, its value is null as the initial instead of the actual spreadsheet as assigned in mainUiApp. Any ideas?

Comment: @FaustoR. Do not use the global variables for handlers and in common, it is good idea to use global variables in GAS. You have to pass the spreadsheet ID also to handler and open it by this id.

Comment: In the global section of the Library, I am not just opening the SS, but also reading some global values from that SS to use across the App. if opening by Id the SS on each handler (and reading those values) is the only solution, it would be frustrating for me, it doesn't look right, is it?

Comment: @FaustoR. I don't know all the details how GAS works but I think this behavior is correct. GAS is a cloud service and I assume calling procedures of a library there is no warranty that they are executed on the same JavaScript engine instance. Even the code can be executed on different servers.

Comment: You are right, maybe i just need to get used to that, thanks a lot for your answers, regards